# Unable to call WebAPI controller from vue js

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-web-api

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022) to create a single-page vuejs application with a WebAPI backend. I want to replace the default WeatherForecastController with one called SearchController. To start with, I created a functionally-identical controller along with a functionally-identical vuejs component. The API call is here:

```
methods: {
        fetchData(): void {
            this.post = null;
            this.loading = true;

            fetch('search')
                .then(r => r.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.post = json as Forecasts;
                    this.loading = false;
                    return;
                });
        }
    }
```

This is identical to the one provided by the template, except I've replaced the string 'weatherforecast' with search. I've also updated the vue.config.js file, replacing the weatherforecast proxy with one for search:

```
proxy: {
    '^/search': {
        target: 'https://localhost:5001/'
    }
}
```

I've updated the main App.vue to import both components, but only the template WeatherForecast component is hitting its controller, even when I've replaced the proxy in the config. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same, and juding by the views of this question, not only me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, the only way I was able to hit other controllers besides the weatherforecast one was by changing the proxy to this instead of having a specified path/target.

`proxy: 'https://localhost:5001/',`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on from where you are fetching data, you have to properly set where is that data. If it is from an external API, you have to put full URL path in your `fetch(path)` function, like "https://www.google.apis.com/weather" for an example. If it is internal, or local API, then just pass the route to the API, like "/myroutetoapi/someparameters" (for an example).

After you made sure you passed the correct path to the API, check if your API actually works. You will have to test and debug your API and its returned values.

I recommend adding `console.log(json);` inside your second `.then()` method. It will show you what you have got. That data will be printed in the console of your browser. Open developer tools and go ahead to "console" tab. Also, you can try visiting that page to your API by putting "localhost:port/myrputetoapi/someparameters" format like in your URL path in your browser.